# Como habilitar WooCommerce Sidebar?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Possuo um site em Wordpress 4.1.15 e utilizo WooCommerce como a loja virtual.

Um dos usuários excluiu as páginas de **Checkout** e **Shop** e quando vi voltei as páginas da lixeira mas depois disso a WooCommerce Sidebar ficou desabilitada e não volta.

Como posso forçar para habilitar novamente a WooCommerce SideBar?

Comment: Já verificou se o plugin esta ativo ?

Comment: Já sim, está tudo funcionando, inclusive os produtos, carrinho e tudo mais... mas a sidebar sumiu

Comment: `http://seusite.com/wp-admin/widgets.php` ?

Comment: Olhe como estão configuradas as informações nos widgets.